# Detect when newly created form is closed

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `Form1` and its my main form.
In some part of my code, I do this:

```
Form2 f2=new Form2(); 
f2. ShowDialog()
```

I want to do following: In Form1, I want to detect when the Form2 closed and do some stuff in that case?
How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to change your `.ShowDialog();` to `.Show(this);` as your code after calling second form would be run after form closed.

You should create a new method for `Closing` event like this:

```
private void FormIsClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // Some stuff you want to do on close
}
```

Then somewhere where you create your `Form2` you need to assign this method to `Closing` event. Do it like this:

```
var f2 = new Form2(); // Create a form
f2.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(FormIsClosing); // Add event handler
f2.Show(this); // Run this form
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Also as I remember you can ommit that long `new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler` when you use `System.Windows.Forms` in your file.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2=new Form2();
        f2.FormClosed += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(this.Form2_FormClosed);
        f2.ShowDialog();
    }

     void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("my code");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to do following: In Form1, i want to detect when the Form2 closed and do some stuff in that case?

*"Detection"* is not necessary as you are using a modal dialog.  You could add an intercept in the dialog class but unless you want to prevent closure, simply perform the following.

Change:

```
Form2 f2=new Form2(); 
f2.ShowDialog()
```

...to:

```
Form2 f2=new Form2(); 
f2.ShowDialog(); // this will block your app until Form2 closes

// If we get here, then it means Form2 has closed
// Add your code here
// ...
// ...
// ...
```